# Scrapy - Retrieve spider object in dupefilter

Tags: python, scrapy

This is scrapy's default `Dupefilter` class method `request_seen`

```
class RFPDupeFilter(BaseDupeFilter):

    def request_seen(self, request):
        fp = self.request_fingerprint(request)
        if fp in self.fingerprints:
            return True
        self.fingerprints.add(fp)
        if self.file:
            self.file.write(fp + os.linesep)
```

While implementing a custom dupefilter. i cannot retrieve the `spider` object from this class unlike other scrapy middleware

Is there any way i can know which `spider` object this is? so i can customize it via a spider on spider basis?

Also i cannot just implement a middleware which reads urls and puts it into a list & checks duplicates instead of a custom dupefilter. This is because i need to pause/resume crawls and need scrapy to store the request  fingerprint by default using the `JOBDIR` setting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really want that, a solution can be to override the [`request_seen`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/457b97c13ccf9a84f3dc7800c180cf059822c09a/scrapy/dupefilters.py#L47) method signature of the `RFPDupeFilter`, so that it receives 2 arguments `(self, request, spider)`;  than you need to override also the scrapy `Scheuler's` [`enqueue_request`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/core/scheduler.py#L50) method because `request_seen` is called inside. You can creat new scheduler and new dupefilter like this:

```
# /scheduler.py

from scrapy.core.scheduler import Scheduler


class MyScheduler(Scheduler):

    def enqueue_request(self, request):
        if not request.dont_filter and self.df.request_seen(request, self.spider):
            self.df.log(request, self.spider)
            return False
        dqok = self._dqpush(request)
        if dqok:
            self.stats.inc_value('scheduler/enqueued/disk', spider=self.spider)
        else:
            self._mqpush(request)
            self.stats.inc_value('scheduler/enqueued/memory', spider=self.spider)
        self.stats.inc_value('scheduler/enqueued', spider=self.spider)
        return True
```

-

```
# /dupefilters.py

from scrapy.dupefilters import RFPDupeFilter


class MyRFPDupeFilter(RFPDupeFilter):

    def request_seen(self, request, spider):
        fp = self.request_fingerprint(request)
        if fp in self.fingerprints:
            return True
        self.fingerprints.add(fp)
        if self.file:
            self.file.write(fp + os.linesep)

        # Do things with spider
```

and set their paths in settings.py:

```
# /settings.py

DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'myproject.dupefilters.MyRFPDupeFilter'
SCHEDULER = 'myproject.scheduler.MyScheduler'
```